# How to add data into SQLite database from recycler view in android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I am writing a code to display recycler view items to a favorites fragment but when I am selecting the favorite button it's not inserting data into the database. Please help me out there. The codes are given below.

The log cat shows: (1) no such table: favorites in "INSERT INTO favorites(Contact,Type,name,image,Favorites_status,Budget) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"

Also, can you please tell me how can I add sharedpreferences to the favorites button.

The db.insert is coming to be -1.

**My FavDB:**

```
package com.example.bottom.Favorites;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel;

public class FavDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "event.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "favorites";
    public static final String COL_ID = "ID";
    public static final String Venue_image = "image";
    public static final String Venue_name = "name";
    public static final String Venue_type = "Type";
    public static final String Venue_budget = "Budget";
    public static final String Venue_contact = "Contact";
    public static final String FAV_STATUS = "Favorites_status";


    public FavDB( Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Venue_name + " TEXT, " +Venue_type+ " TEXT, " +Venue_budget+ " TEXT, "+Venue_image+ " TEXT, "+Venue_contact+ " TEXT, "+FAV_STATUS+ " TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(" drop table if exists " +TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }


        'inserting the data into database'
     public boolean inserttVenueData(FavVenueItem favVenueItem) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Venue_name, favVenueItem.getVenuename());
        cv.put(Venue_image, favVenueItem.getImageResourse());
        cv.put(Venue_type, favVenueItem.getType());
        cv.put(Venue_budget, favVenueItem.getBudget());
        cv.put(Venue_contact, favVenueItem.getContact());
        cv.put(FAV_STATUS, 1);
        long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

        if (result == -1){

            Log.d("not added","the venue was not added");
            return false;
        }else {
            Log.d("added", "the venue was added");
            return true;}
    }
```

**My VenueAdapter:**

```
    package com.example.bottom.Favorites;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.bottom.R;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class VenueAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VenueAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<FavVenueItem> VenueItemsList;
    private Context context;
    private FavDB favDB;


    public VenueAdapter(ArrayList<FavVenueItem> VenueItems, Context context) {
        this.VenueItemsList = VenueItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        favDB = new FavDB(context);
      

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rows,
                parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

   
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final FavVenueItem venueItem = VenueItemsList.get(position);

        holder.ImageView.setImageResource(VenueItemsList.get(position).getImageResourse());
        holder.Name.setText(VenueItemsList.get(position).getVenuename());
        holder.venuetype.setText(VenueItemsList.get(position).getType());
        holder.venuebudget.setText(VenueItemsList.get(position).getBudget());
        holder.venuecontact.setText(VenueItemsList.get(position).getContact());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return VenueItemsList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        ImageView ImageView;
        TextView Name, venuetype, venuebudget, venuecontact;
        Button favbtn;
//        FloatingActionButton fab1;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.venueimage);
            Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.venunename);
            venuetype = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            venuebudget = itemView.findViewById(R.id.budget);
            venuecontact = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact);
            favbtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favbtn);


            favbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    FavVenueItem venueItem = VenueItemsList.get(position);


                    if (venueItem.getFavStatus().equals("0")) {
                        venueItem.setFavStatus("1");
                        favDB.inserttVenueData(venueItem);
                        Log.d("clicked", "button clicked");


                       favbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_24);


                    } else {
                        venueItem.setFavStatus("0");
                        favbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_border_24);

                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**My FavVenueItem: (Model)**

```
package com.example.bottom.Favorites;

public class FavVenueItem {
    private int imageResourse;
    private String venuename;
    private String type;
    private String budget;
    private String contact;
    private String favStatus;

    public FavVenueItem(){}

    public FavVenueItem(int imageResourse,String venuename, String favStatus, String type, String budget, String contact, String key_id){
        this.imageResourse=imageResourse;
        this.venuename=venuename;
        this.type=type;
        this.budget=budget;
        this.contact=contact;
        this.favStatus=favStatus;
    }

    public int getImageResourse() {
        return imageResourse;
    }

    public void setImageResourse(int imageResourse) {
        this.imageResourse = imageResourse;
    }

    public String getVenuename() {
        return venuename;
    }

    public void setVenuename(String venuename) {
        this.venuename = venuename;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getBudget() {
        return budget;
    }

    public void setBudget(String budget) {
        this.budget = budget;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getFavStatus() {
        return favStatus;
    }

    public void setFavStatus(String favStatus) {
        this.favStatus = favStatus;
    }

}
```

**My Fragment:**

```
package com.example.bottom;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.bottom.Favorites.FavVenueItem;
import com.example.bottom.Favorites.VenueAdapter;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VenueListFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<FavVenueItem> VenueItems = new ArrayList<>();
    FloatingActionButton fab1;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.venuelist, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.vendors_list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new VenueAdapter(VenueItems,getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));



        setData();




        return v;


    }

    private void setData() {

        VenueItems.add(new FavVenueItem(R.drawable.theritvaan, "The Ritvaan", "0", "Wedding venue", "1000/plate onwards", "1234567891", "0"));
        VenueItems.add(new FavVenueItem(R.drawable.theshaurya, "The Shaurya", "0", "Wedding venue", "2000/plate onwards", "1234567891", "1"));
        VenueItems.add(new FavVenueItem(R.drawable.diamondcrown, "Diamond Crown", "0", "Wedding venue", "1100/plate onwards", "1234567891", "2"));
        VenueItems.add(new FavVenueItem(R.drawable.theimperialboutique, "The Imperial Boutique", "0", "Wedding venue", "1000/plate onwards", "1234567891", "3"));

    }
}
```

please help me out!
thanks a ton!

Comment: Check if the table you are querying/insering to exist?

Comment: can you log your venuitem in the button click like Log.d("venuItem",new Gson().toJson(venueItem));

Comment: @DharmenderManral  my logcat shows this: 
 2021-06-23 00:13:34.177 14472-14472/com.example.bottom D/not added: the venue was not added
2021-06-23 00:13:34.205 14472-14472/com.example.bottom D/venuItem: {"budget":"1000/plate onwards","contact":"1234567891","favStatus":"1","imageResourse":2131165335,"type":"Wedding venue","venuename":"The Ritvaan"}

Comment: @ShekharSuman the logcat says no such table exists, ,can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: @NehaM. You can oncreate() method on constructor call for the purpose of fixing this issue. if you are planning to use this db in a complicated app. i would suggest creating a DBManger class that  you can use to create and initialise all the tables of the app in one place. there are many DBManager class examples you can find in GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below query, It seems you are passing int value in status column.

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Venue_name + " TEXT, " + Venue_type + " TEXT, " + Venue_budget + " TEXT, " + Venue_image + " TEXT, " + Venue_contact + " TEXT, " + FAV_STATUS + " INTEGER" + ")");

}
```

Comment: before execute this query uninstall the previous app from mobile

Comment: Deleting the existing database helped, thanks!